Android Nested Recyclerview Implementation
I have onButton click in helper class which has update method which sets/updates the child recycler view for child items. Singlehash in this activity stores the selected pouch items. The problem here is whenever the update method is called even if I select any other items from the list it keeps updating all the selected parent items with same child recycler view list. I want to implement in a way that if I select child items for one item then it should assign to that item only. It should not refresh the parent list and assign same child items to all. How can I implement that? Modify my code accordingly.
@Override
    public void onButtonClick(int bbClickPos) {
        GetArticlesByTagId item = pouchesList.get(bbClickPos);

        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_listview, null);
        //recyclerview layout
        serviceListRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.serviceListRecycler);
        builder.setView(view);
        if (all_items.isEmpty() || all_items.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            adapter = new customPouchListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), all_items, selectedItems, getResources().getString(R.string.selectIns),
                    "na", "na", this);
            //adding data to recycler view
            serviceListRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
            serviceListRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        }

        Button btnConfirm = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
        TextView pouchListTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.hamMenuTitle);
        customList = builder.create();
        customList.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        customList.show();
        pouchListTitle.setText(R.string.selectIns);
        btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                update(bbClickPos);
                customList.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    private void update(int pos){
        customTagsAdapter = new CustomTagsAdapter(context, singleHash, pouchesList, this, this::onButtonClick, viewPool);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(customTagsAdapter);
        customTagsAdapter.notifyItemChanged(pos);
    }

This is my button click method.
Here's my bind view holder for parent adapter.
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        GetArticlesByTagId item = this.dataList.get(position);

        String splited = item.getType().toLowerCase().split(" ")[0];

//       // holder.textView.setText(item.getType().toUpperCase());

        //item counter
        holder.inc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                item.incrementCounter();
                holder.count.setText(String.valueOf(item.getCounter()));
            }
        });

        holder.dec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                item.decrementCounter();
                holder.count.setText(String.valueOf(item.getCounter()));
            }
        });

        // Set listener for checkbox clicks
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            if (isChecked){
                if (splited.equals("pouches") || splited.equals("pouch")) {
                    holder.itemCounter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.bb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (this.dataList.size() == 1){
                        buttonView.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }else {
                    holder.itemCounter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.bb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }else {
                item.setClicked(false);
                holder.itemCounter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.bb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.childRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (checkboxClickListener != null) {
                int pp = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                if (pp != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    checkboxClickListener.onCheckboxClicked(pp, isChecked);
                }
            }
        });

        holder.checkBox.setChecked(item.isSelected());
        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                item.setSelected(((CheckBox) v).isChecked());
            }
        });

        holder.bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pp = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                if (pp != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    item.setClicked(true);
                    onPouchItemsButtonClickListner.onButtonClick(pp);
                }
            }
        });

        if (item.isClicked()){
            if (holder.childRecycler.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                holder.childRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //set pouch instruments
                setPouchInstruments(holder.childRecycler, holder.getAdapterPosition(), pouchItems);
            }
        }
}

Here's view holder for child adapter:
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChildAdapter.ChildViewHolder holder, int position) {
//        Log.d("child", " This is child running" +  ss.entrySet().size());
        if( this.i < ss.entrySet().size())
        {
//            Log.d("child", " This is child running" +  ss.entrySet().size());
            holder.ins_name.setText(this.keys.get(i));
            holder.count.setText(this.values.get(i));
            this.i++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
//        Log.d("newitems", "list size is " + ss.size());
        return ss.size();

    }

    public static class ChildViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView ins_name, count;
        Button inc, dec;

        public ChildViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView,  final onItemAddListener listener, int position, ArrayList<String> keys) {
            super(itemView);

            ins_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ins_name);
            count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ins_count);
            inc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.incbtn);
            dec = itemView.findViewById(R.id.decbtn);
            inc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
//                    Log.d("child", ins_name.getText().toString() + " is it true " + keys.contains(ins_name.getText().toString()));
                    listener.onIncclick(getAdapterPosition(), position, ins_name.getText().toString(), "increase");
                }
            });

            dec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onIncclick(getAdapterPosition(), position, ins_name.getText().toString(), "decrease");
                }
            });
        }
    }

